# Angular Test In Jasmine Promises Won't Digest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am writing my first Angular test, in Jasmine, and I cannot seem to get a promise to digest in a mock service. 
Here is my controller (which is being tested) and the resource it uses:

```
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp.login', [
       'ngCookies',
       'ngResource'
    ])

    /*Controllers*/
    .controller('login', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$cookies', 'LoginService', function ($scope, $rootScope, $cookies, LoginService) {
        $scope.user = {};
        $scope.user.username = "";
        $scope.user.password = "";

        var loginError = function () {
            console.log("failure logging in")
        };
        var loginSuccess = function (result) {
            $cookies.put('authToken', result.token);
            $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
        };
        $scope.login = function () {
            var credentials = {username: $scope.user.username, password: $scope.user.password};
            var tokenPromise = LoginService.authenticate(credentials);
            console.log(tokenPromise);
            tokenPromise.$promise.then(loginSuccess, loginError);
        }
    }])

    /*Resources*/
    .factory('LoginService', ['$resource', 'apiUrl', function ($resource, apiUrl) {
        return $resource(
            apiUrl + 'auth/token/',
            {},
            {
                authenticate: {
                    method: "POST"
                }
            }
        )
    }]);
```

Below is the *current* version of the test.

```
describe('myApp.login', function () {
    var createController, scope, deferred, LoginService;
    var successToken = {'token': 'tokenGoesHere'}

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $injector, $q, $timeout) {
        var cookies = $injector.get('$cookies');
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        LoginService = { authenticate: function(user) {
            deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function(){
                deferred.resolve(successToken);
                $rootScope.$apply();
                $rootScope.$digest();
            }, 1000);
            $timeout.flush();
            return deferred.promise;
        }};
            return $controller('login', {
                '$scope': scope,
                '$cookies': cookies,
                'LoginService': LoginService
            });
        };
    }));
    it('Should set cookie with returned JWT', function() {
        var controller = new createController();
        scope.user.username = 'username';
        scope.user.password = 'password';
        scope.login();
    });
});
```

I've tried a `$timeout`, `setTimeout`, `spyOn`, and a few others, but nothing I try returns the promise in the state that the controller expects, and I end up getting the following stacktrace:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0) myApp.login Should set cookie with returned JWT FAILED
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'tokenPromise.$promise.then')
        at /home/anton/git/persist-ng/app/login/login.js:53
        at /home/anton/git/persist-ng/app/login/login_test.js:42
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.041 secs / 0.007 secs)
```

Any help is appreciated, even if the issue actually lives in the code itself, not the test.

Comment: Just return `{$promise: deferred.promise}` in your mock LoginService

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly.